# Does stripe automatically set a subscription back to 'active' if one of the automatic retries succeed?

Tags: stripe-payments

If [Stripe](https://stripe.com) fails to collect payment for a [Subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions) on the 1st attempt, but succeeds on the 2nd automatic retry, (i.e via a succesful automatic [Recovery Process](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/lifecycle#settings)), does it ***automatically*** transition the subscription from `status = 'past_due'` to `status = 'active'`?

I'm reading [Stripe Docs: Lifecycle#reactivate](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/lifecycle#reactivate):

> To set a subscription status from an unpaid or past_due state back to active, open the most recent invoice and attempt to pay it. Note that paying any other invoice—one that is not the most recent invoice—does not change the subscription’s status.

Does the above note apply only for Subscriptions where the Recovery Process failed or do I always need to manually open the most recent invoice and pay it to transition back to `status = 'active'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the most recent invoice on a Subscription is paid, the Subscription would  have `status` set to `active`. So whether you pay it manually, or automatic retries pay the invoice, it will automatically move the Subscription back to active.